# How to replace text inside specific elements using javascript or any other qualified language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I have this block of HTML(i don't want to change the code):

```
<section class="welcome-block-top">
                <div class="inside">
                    <h2>Start a good life</h2>
                    <label>text to replace 1</label> 
                    <a href="" class="link-a">
                        some text i do not want to replace</a>
                </div>
            </section>
```

i want to replace the text "text to replace 1"

i also want to replace text here:

```
        <h3>
            <span>
            text to replace 2                   </span>
        </h3>
```

please teach me masters, i searched Google and stack-overflow and i dont seem to get something that works in my situation.

Something using the onload js method is preferable because the webpage is dynamically loaded.

**if you know a better method to do this with any other language don't hesitate to inform me.**

If there is a method to clear the text inside the elements and then insert new text i would be grateful.

Comment: if you're using jquery, you should learn to use selectors to select the elements you want, then learn about methods like text() and html() to alter their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which can easily change the content of the tags.

```
oldContent = $("div.inside label:first").html();
$("div.inside label:first").html("put your desired content here");
```

meaining that find `first` `label` tag in the `div` tag having `inside` class and change its `html` content with the parameter.

**EDIT:**

You can of course save the old content and use it.

```
$("div.inside label:first").html(oldContent + " new content");
```

or

```
$("div.inside label:first").append(" new content");
```

Comment: will this remove the old text or will the old text stay?

Edit: will text this now

Comment: You can save the old content and use it later. Check the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your real use case but it might be this :

```
$('*:not(:has(*))').text(function(_,t){
  return t.replace("text to replace 1", "replacement")
});
```

The main idea here is to apply a transformation to the text of all elements with no children (leafs in the DOM tree).

If you have more complex needs, or performance requirements, you might want to have a look at dedicated libraries, like mine : https://github.com/Canop/groumf

Comment: awesome library will take a closer look at it in my free time.